# Mysql Search In serailized string

Tags: mysql

I want to get concatenated list of values from serialized string using MySQL query.The sample string is

```
a:4:{s:11:"customersId";i:381032;s:12:"commerceName";s:9:"amazonmws";s:9:"serviceId";i:32042;s:9:"trackings";a:2:{i:0;a:10:{s:12:"customers_id";i:381032;s:13:"commerce_name";s:9:"amazonmws";s:10:"service_id";i:32042;s:15:"commerce_ref_id";s:19:"112-1414980-3467405";s:12:"order_number";i:151434392;s:11:"tracking_no";s:15:"995365613134160";s:7:"carrier";s:3:"FDX";s:8:"order_id";i:151434392;s:7:"details";a:1:{i:0;a:2:{s:4:"wsku";s:12:"KZW4OC-F0015";s:3:"qty";s:9:"000000001";}}s:20:"commerce_account_key";N;}i:1;a:10:{s:12:"customers_id";i:381032;s:13:"commerce_name";s:9:"amazonmws";s:10:"service_id";i:32042;s:15:"commerce_ref_id";s:19:"002-5809777-9709040";s:12:"order_number";i:151536332;s:11:"tracking_no";s:15:"995365613134153";s:7:"carrier";s:3:"FDX";s:8:"order_id";i:151536332;s:7:"details";a:1:{i:0;a:2:{s:4:"wsku";s:12:"KZW4OC-F0011";s:3:"qty";s:9:"000000001";}}s:20:"commerce_account_key";N;}}}
```

I want the list of  values next to key order_id in above string.
I have tried with substring_index.
Please find my sample query

```
select SUBSTRING_INDEX(substring_index('serialized_sting','"order_id";i:',-1),';s:7:',1)
```

I get only one value from string,but not all

Comment: If you need to process your data then you must normalize your structure, i.e. deserialize it and put each value into separate column.

Comment: That is an PHP Array that has been put through a `serialize()` function. To make sense of it it would be best to fetch the data into PHP and `unserialize()` it back into an array.

Comment: But requirement is to fetch using mysql query

Comment: That really is not the job of SQL, if this is homework, maybe it is to demonstrate how doing things like this is not helpful when you want to use only SQL to process it.